# If $f: X \to Y$ and continuous in $D \in \mathcal{B}_{X}$, then $V$ open implies $f^{-1}(V) = U \cap D$ with $U$ open

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

I am reading through Yeh's *Real Analysis* 3rd edition, pp. 21-22. Yeh proves the following theorem:

> Given two measurable spaces $(X, \mathcal{B}_X)$ and $(Y, \mathcal{B}_Y)$ where $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces and $\mathcal{B}_X$ and $\mathcal{B}_Y$ are the Borel $\sigma$-algebras of subsets of $X$ and $Y$ respectively, if $f$ is a continuous mapping defined on a set $D \in \mathcal{B}_X$, then $f$ is a $\mathcal{B}_X$/$\mathcal{B}_Y$-measurable mapping of $D$ into $Y$.

In the above, it is understood that the domain and range of $f$ satisfy $\mathcal{D}(f) \subset X$ and $\mathcal{R}(f) \subset Y$ respectively.

Yeh starts off the proof as follows:

> Let $V$ be an open set in $Y$. The continuity of $f$ on $D$ implies that $f^{-1}(V) = U \cap D$ where $U$ is an open set in $X$ so that $f^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal{B}_X$.

I don't follow this part of the proof, and I suspect it's because my background in topology is lacking.

Every topology text I have that I've opened up has something like the following:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces. $f: X \to Y$ is continuous if $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $X$ for every open set $V$ in $Y$.

Great, so that means that $f^{-1}(V)$ should be open, but why does it equal $U \cap D$? Why does this matter anyway, since $\mathcal{B}_X$ is the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the collection of all open sets of $X$ anyway, so $f^{-1}(V) \in \mathcal{B}_X$ should be obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That $f\colon D\to Y$ is continuous means that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $D$ whenever $V$ is open in $Y$.

However, we did not specify a topology on $D$. Typically, when nothing is explicitly stated, we take the *subspace topology* on $D$. In the subspace topology, a set $E \subseteq D$ is open if there is some $F\subseteq X$ that is open in $X$ such that $E=D\cap F$.

Thus, that $f^{-1}(V)$ is open in $D$ means that there is a $U$ that is open in $X$ so that $f^{-1}(V) = D \cap U$.

Answer (score 2):

This is about the subspace topology.

Given a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ and a subset $S\subseteq X$, the subspace topology on $S$ is defined as

$$\mathcal{T}_S := \{S\cap U\mid U \in \mathcal{T}\}$$

In other words, your open sets on $S$ are presicely the intersections of $S$ with open sets $U$ that are elements of your given topology $\mathcal{T}$.